# Vba assistance for filtered randomizer

Tags: vba, excel

Hello guys I have the following code made to be a randomizer, however is not giving me the proper results that I expected, here are the results needed

1- It doesn't matter which manager name do you put it always give you the same data no matter how many rows you have on the raw data

2- Also I need the randomizer to look for the current week number and if there's no data to go back to the previous week, this I don't know how to do it so any assistance will be amazing

At the end there are some images for more insight on the issue

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lr As Long, wks As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Sheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    With ActiveSheet

        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:H" & lr).Sort key1:=.Range("G1"), Header:=xlYes

        .Range("A1:H" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>" &  

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

        .Rows("1:" & lr).Delete Shift:=xlUp

        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

        If lr > 5 Then

            .Range("I2:I" & lr).Formula = "=RAND()"

            .Calculate

            .Range("I2:I" & lr).Value = .Range("I2:I" & lr).Value

            wks.Range("A5:H9").Value = .Range("A1:H5").Value

        Else

            MsgBox "Please enter a valid login in order to continue"

        End If

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        .Delete

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End With

    wks.Activate

    wks.Range("A5:H9").Sort key1:=wks.Range("A5"), Header:=xlNo

    Set wks = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvrgJ.png

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/msRXy.png

Comment: Does this code actually compile? Did you lose something when copy/pasting?

Comment: @Freeman Yes it does, I copy and paste via cellphone so only the indentation was a bit off, but aside from that it does compile

Comment: This line: `.Range("A1:H" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>" &` (following `With ActiveSheet`) is missing something...

Comment: oh I see, its actually a whole string like this I think that it got missed on the copy and paste via phone .Range("A1:H" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

Comment: You generated a series of rand number. Shouldn't you sort by that number to get randomized data?

Comment: @sekiro89 please [edit] that into your OP. That's very difficult to read in the comments & comments can get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to pick 5 random records from the "Data" sheet and populate them in the table on the "Audit" sheet. You did not provide the sheet names so I've made some assumptions in my code, you can modify to fit.

This is just the Random Record Picker. You can filter the set you are picking from however you want before this runs.

```
Sub getRandomRecords()

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim shAudit As Worksheet
    Dim shData As Worksheet
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim key As Variant


    Set shAudit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = shData.Range("A" & shData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Pick 5 random records with no repeats
    Do Until dict.Count = 5
        r = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(2, lastRow)
        If Not dict.Exists(r) Then
            dict.Add r, r
        End If
    Loop

    r = 0

    'Copy the randomly selected records to the audit tab
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        shData.Range("A1:H1").Offset(key - 1, 0).Copy shAudit.Range("A5:H5").Offset(r, 0)
        r = r + 1
    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Valon, kind of like that only that the person accessing the file needs to put their login under below the enter your login cell (a2) and then they get only their information to populate, like doing a match between audit and raw.

Comment: I got it to work with that code that you provided, thanks for the assistance Valon, hope that you have a good one and a nice weekend.